# OAuth2 authentication from a mobile client using Facebook or Google or any other third-parties

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I've implemented an OAuth2 Server which currently handles two grant types, `password` and `refresh_token`.

Now, I need to allow my clients to authenticate using their Facebook or Google account, but my question may apply to any similar flow.

To authenticate against Facebook or Google, the user needs to authorize my application to fetch its data, then I need to access Facebook or Google to actually fetch them.

I though about two ways of doing it.

1. The user log in into its Facebook Account, authorize my application and retrieve an Access Token. It sends its Access Token to my server and I use it to fetch its data.
2. The user log in into its Facebook Account, authorize my application and get an Authorization Code, it sends it to my server, I use its Authorization Code to get an Access Token for the user, and use it to fetch its data.

From your experience and/or best practices (I was not able to find any about this kind of workflow), what is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

At my workplace, the 2nd type (called explicit grant type) is used. It is preferred over the first one (called implicit grant type.)

One more advantage of explicit grant type over implicit grant type is that it supports the refresh token which implicit does not support that in a nutshell means either you have to keep a very long expiry time of your access token or the user have to do the redirection dance once the token expires.

So you are more secure with explicit grant type as the expiry time of the access token need not to be very high (I believe you can not change the expiry time of access token when using with facebook or google ) and it does not requires redirection thing (re-login)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there are some really good points. I just tried to implement such behavior, and for testing purpose I manually do the `authorize` request, but I need to provide a `redirect_uri` and I need to re-use it to get `access_token` with the `authorization_code`, is there something I'm missing here? There is no need of this `redirect_uri` because the `authorization_code` should be get by the mobile device and then sent to my server as a custom grant type on my own server. any hints?

Comment: @Trent As per my understanding, `redirect_uri` will be needed only for getting the `access_code` if redirection method is used. If you have the access_code you can get the access_token and hence all the access to authorized resources. I have used `Login using google` thing for my personal projects, and it does not uses the redirection but instead a popup-dialog thing. I don't have much experience with mobile stuff, but in general if you are getting `access_code` from the device you don't need `redirect_uri`

Comment: afaik, there is no other method to get an `access_code`, the following request `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=&client_id=someappid&response_type=code` redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri&client_id=someappid&response_type=code
` which returns an error because of the missing `redirect_uri`, I may obviously set a dummy `redirect_uri` on both client & server but it doesn't feel right.